# Is it possible to run projects on real devices using Xcode 8 without enrolling to Apple's Developer Program?

Tags: ios, xcode8

Its not every time we create a **real** Xcode project, sometimes we need to create project for R&D purpose also. And to test a R&D project sometimes we need to use real device. But I'm unable to run a R&D project on real devices in Xcode 8, whereas in Xcode 7 or Prior to Xcode 8 version we can.

Is there any way to to run test projects on real device without registering?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it over the wire, i.e. you can install it directly from Xcode but not via submitting it to TestFlight etc.

To install into device, directly from Xcode, you would still need to have a developer account with Apple - to get developer provisioning profile and certificate. W/o developer account, even installing directly from Xcode is not possible.

Also, Xcode 8 support for devices start from iOS8. Any device prior to iOS 8 is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the below link is for Xcode 7, but am sure it should work for Xcode 8 as well.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244801

Also, it expires after 7 days. So, the app should be installed again manually within that period.

Comment: No, It will not.  Settings has been changed for Xcode 8.

Comment: Sorry, as I haven't checked it on Xcode 8, with me enrolling in the developer program. :-/